# jquery json looping not showing the output

Tags: jquery, json

I'm a new programmer trying to learn JSON and JQUERY.

I want to get data from a url, which works but it wont work when I apply the for loop for some reason. I tried looking online but it all didn't seem to work.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('myurlgoeshere', function(data){

        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            document.write(data.members[i].members);
        }

    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

My Json code looks like this (removed the data in the arrays since this is private, sorry.)

```
{
"channels": [],
"instant_invite": null,
"id": "574592393862708225",
"members": [],
"name": "553b"
}
```

I want it to loop so that it shows all the current members for example. But when I apply this code nothing shows at all (no error as well).

Comment: I ran your example and `data.length` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't want to iterate the entire returned JSON but only the `members` section of the response.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('myurlgoeshere', function(data) {

        // checking if the "data.members" node exists. 
        // You could extend the check wit " && data.members.length" to make sure the returned element is iterable
        if (data && data.members) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.members.length; i++) {
                document.write(data.members[i]);
            }
        } else {
            document.write("Returned content did not contain the required 'members' node");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @TestinJast could you add a sample of what is contained in the `members` array? Just X out names and addresses to make sure you don't post sensitive data.

Comment: Great! I think problem was that it said `data.members[i].members` in my first draft, my bad. Would you mark the answer as solution in that case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, again, thank you. The problem was on my end, It was ```data.members[i].username```.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sample as html/JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fntTest2 (data){

    //for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(i = 0; i < data.members.length; i++) {
        alert(data.members[i].members);
    }

}

var json1 = {
"channels": [],
"instant_invite": null,
"id": "574592393862708225",
"members": [],
"name": "553b"
};

var json2 = {
"channels": [],
"instant_invite": null,
"id": "574592393862708225",
"members": [{
"members": "0",
"A": "12345",
"B": "12345",
"C": "12345",
"D": "12345",
},
{
"members": "1",
"A": "12389",
"B": "12389",
"C": "12389",
"D": "12389",
}],
"name": "553b"
};

fntTest2(json1);
fntTest2(json2);
</script>
```